# Is there an elegant way to exclude the first value of a range?

Tags: ruby, range

Let's say I have a range from 0 to 10:

```
range = 0...10
```

Three dots mean, that the last value (10) is excluded:

```
range.include? 10
=> false
```

Now, is there a similar and elegant way to exclude the *first* value?
For the above example, this would mean to include all values that are *bigger* (`>`, *not* `>=`) than 0 and *smaller* than 10.

Comment: I think that excluding the last value is often quite useful such as `range = 0...something.size` What is your usecase for needing to exclude the _first_ value?

Comment: I check if a certain set of values are within that range. I just want to handle zero values differently.  
I know how to achieve this, but I was curious, if there is something similar like `...` to exclude the *first* value of a range.

Comment: I've learned more about range in 5 minutes than in the last year. Thanks!

Comment: I want to include *all* numbers bigger than 0. For example, 0.0000001 (and even smaller numbers) should be included, too. (Please see my comment on the answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

```
((0+1)..10)
```

Comment: The only problem with this would be, that values between 0 and 1 would not be included. Yes, you can say `0.00000001..10` (or something similar, depending on how many decimals you need). But that's rather ugly, IMO, when the thing I want to say is: `0 < range < 10`.

Comment: Since Ruby 2.2 you can use `(0.0).next_float..10.0`

Comment: Or, my preferred syntax: `0.to_f.next_float..10`

Comment: @Envek - You should make that a separate answer. Worked for perfectly for my use case!

Answer (score 6):

I have two suggestions for you, they're not very ideal but they're the best I can think of.

First you can define a new method on the Range class that does what you describe. It'd look like this:

```
class Range
  def have?(x)
    if x == self.begin
      false
    else
      include?(x)
    end
  end
end

p (0..10).have?(0)       #=> false
p (0..10).have?(0.00001) #=> true
```

I don't know, I just used a synonym of "include" as a method name, maybe you can think of something better. But that's the idea.

And then you could do something a little more elaborate, and define a method on the Range class that marks a range as one you want to exclude the beginning value of, and then change Range's `include?` method to check for that mark.

```
class Range
  def exclude_begin
    @exclude_begin = true
    self
  end

  alias_method :original_include?, :include?
  def include?(x)
    return false if x == self.begin && instance_variable_defined?(:@exclude_begin)
    original_include?(x)
  end

  alias_method :===, :include?
  alias_method :member?, :include?
end

p (0..10).include?(0)                     #=> true
p (0..10).include?(0.00001)               #=> true
p (0..10).exclude_begin.include?(0)       #=> false
p (0..10).exclude_begin.include?(0.00001) #=> true
```

Again, you may want a better (more elegant?) name for the method than `exclude_begin`, I just chose that since it's consistent with Range's `exclude_end?` method.

**Edit:** I've got another one for you, just because I find this problem so interesting. :P This'll only work in the very latest version of Ruby 1.9, but will allow the following syntax:

```
(0.exclude..10).include? 0       #=> false
(0.exclude..10).include? 0.00001 #=> true
```

It uses the same idea as my 2nd suggestion, but stores the "exclusion marker" in the number instead of the range. I have to use Ruby 1.9's SimpleDelegator to accomplish this (numbers on their own can't have instance variables or anything), which is why it won't work in earlier versions of Ruby.

```
require "delegate"

class Numeric
  def exclude
    o = SimpleDelegator.new(self)
    def o.exclude_this?() true end
    o
  end
end

class Range
  alias_method :original_include?, :include?
  def include?(x)
    return false if x == self.begin &&
                    self.begin.respond_to?(:exclude_this?) &&
                    self.begin.exclude_this?
    original_include?(x)
  end

  alias_method :===, :include?
  alias_method :member?, :include?
end
```

Comment: Wow. That's a great answer. Thanks a lot! I am still busy trying to understand your Ruby 1.9 solution. It's great to see what's possible. However, I think the most elegant and most obvious solution IMO would be to describe a range with excluding start and end values by four dots: `0....10`. I am really not sure if this is even possible without messing around with the range.c file!?

Comment: Yeah, I agree that would be a nice syntax, but it would require a change to the Ruby grammar (it causes a syntax error if you type it in). One thing you can do close to that in Ruby 1.9 is use my last example there, but name the method `call` instead of `exclude`. Then you can use Ruby's new syntax sugar and write `0.()..10` and get the same thing. `0.()` is a shortcut for the `call` method. I don't know if that's better or not, though. :P

Comment: Yeah, nice. But this would mean total confusion, I guess. ;-) I'd rather stick to your `(0..10).exclude_begin` or `0.exclude..10` solutions. Thanks for your answer again. I learned a lot. (I accepted another answer, because I wouldn't describe this as an elegant solution similar to the three dot notation to exclude the last value).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create your own range type.

```
class FancyRange
  def initialize(minimum, maximum, exclusive_minimum, exclusive_maximum)
    # insert code here
  end

  # insert more code here

end
```