# Is there a way to iterate over a range, excluding a value

Tags: ruby

I need to iterate over an array, excluding a value in the middle. I know I can do

```
 (0..10).each do |i|
     unless i==6
         ...
     end
  end
```

But I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way. The closest solution I found was this:

[Is there an elegant way to exclude the first value of a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358788/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-exclude-the-first-value-of-a-range)

I need to do this to iterate through poorly organized data I was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((0..10).to_a - [6]).each do |i|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make usage of `reject` method to accomplish it.

I don't know if its a cleaner way but it is just another way.

```
(0..10).reject { |v| v == 6 }.each do |i|
```

Give a shot and tell me what do you think about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it cleaner or preferred way for your simple case, but you can do something like

```
(0..10).select{|i| i!=6}.each do
  # YOUR CODE
end
```

in more complex cases this is definitely a way

P.S. while writing the answer, the answer with **reject** one arrived :) this is almost the same one, i just forgot of reject, remembered only select :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `next` if you just want to get around wrapping your code in an `unless` block. For example, if you want to skip a set of numbers, you can do something like:

```
skip_values = [3, 6, 7]
(0..10).each do |i|
  # When i is 3, 6, or 7, continue to the next iteration
  next if skip_values.include?(i)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could define a subclass or patch Range itself with something like...

```
  def reach not_this_one
    each do |x|
      yield x unless x == not_this_one
    end
  end
```

...or perhaps...

```
  def reach not_this_one, &block
    self.select { |x| x != not_this_one }.each &block
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily exclude a value by using [`Enumerable#grep_v`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v):

```
(1..5).grep_v(2).each { |n| puts n }
#1
#3
#4
#5
```

Unfortunately `grep_v` like some of the other posted answers creates an intermediate array. To be honest I prefer your initial approach, which can be written more neatly (without monkey-patching) as:

```
(1..5).each { |n| puts n unless n == 2 }
#1
#3
#4
#5
```