# Why is ActiveRecord::where producing incorrect SQL for less than?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to use the "where" query with numeric comparisons, as follows:

```
above = BranchOption.where('order < ?', @branch_option.order).first
```

but the SQL it produces doesn't work (notice the lack the table information and double quotes):

```
SELECT  "branch_options".* FROM "branch_options" WHERE (order < 2)  ORDER BY "branch_options"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

If I am explicit with my where call, I can get the answer I want, but this isn't very portable:

```
above = BranchOption.where('"branch_options"."order" < ?', @branch_option.order).first
# >> SELECT  "branch_options".* FROM "branch_options" WHERE ("branch_options"."order" < 2)  ORDER BY "branch_options"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

In general, where seems to be behaving correctly, eg:

```
zeroes = BranchOption.where(order: 0)
# >> SELECT "branch_options".* FROM "branch_options" WHERE "branch_options"."order" = ?  [["order", 2]]
```

I am using rails 4.2.1, and SQLite3 (running in OSX using Tokaido).

The relevant table (from schema.rb) is as follows:

```
create_table "branch_options", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "prose"
    t.integer  "order"
    t.integer  "origin_id"
    t.integer  "destination_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end

add_index "branch_options", ["destination_id"], name: "index_branch_options_on_destination_id"
add_index "branch_options", ["origin_id"], name: "index_branch_options_on_origin_id"
```

And the model branch_option.rb looks like this:

```
class BranchOption < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :origin, class_name: "Chapter", inverse_of: :branch_options
    belongs_to :destination, class_name: "Chapter"
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been looking for answers for a long time now, but can't find anything.

Comment: It's **not** producing the wrong SQL. It's producing exactly the SQL you asked it to. It doesn't parse/pick apart manually built-up query strings.

Comment: Right - it's the SQL I asked for, but not the SQL I wanted. Although I understood from the documentation that rails does pick apart manual query strings, eg: Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders]) should work - this example is taken from [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Also, other people seem to be able to use #where in this manner, for example the "correct" answer on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317662/rails-using-greater-than-less-than-with-a-where-statement) uses the syntax `User.where("id > ?", 200) `

Comment: Both of those examples behave **identically** to the example in your question. `.where('id > ?', 100)` will produce `select ... where id > 100`, *not* `select ... where "table_name"."id" > 100`.

Comment: They certainly do! So, using your example, how would you go about extracting all records that have an id over 100?

Comment: `.where('id > 100')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are providing a fragment of sql rails just fills in the placeholders - nothing more, nothing less.

In particular since your column name is an sql keyword you will need to quote it yourself. You can use the ActiveRecord quoting functions to do the quoting portably - the connection class has a `quote_column_name` function.

Unfortunately the set of operations ActiveRecord will generate sql for isn't very wide, although there are libraries such as [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/commits/master) that allow you to express more queries without resorting to sql fragments. They do tend to be break on rails upgrades though, since they are by nature tightly coupled to active record internals.

Comment: Thanks Frederick, the problem was indeed that my column name was also an SQL keyword. Using a different column name, or quoting it using the method you suggested, works perfectly. Incidentally, I also found [a way to do it using ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23936233/6142572), that [also works for floating point values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3358795/6142572)

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
above = BranchOption.where(["order < ?", @branch_option.order]).first
```